# Why doesn't the law of total expectation apply here? $E[X] = E[E[X \mid Y]]$

Tags: probability, entropy

I'm learning about Entropy for the first time. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy),

$$H(Y \mid X = x) = E[I(Y) \mid X=x]$$

and the confusing part for me is this statement: " $H(Y \mid X)$ is the result of averaging $H(Y \mid X = x)$ over all possible values $x$ that $X$ may take. "

This reminds me exactly of $E[X] = E[E[X|Y]]$.

**My question**

It seems to me $H(Y \mid X)$ should equal $H(Y)$ but this is wrong. Here's why I think this... because of the total law of expectation,

$$H(Y \mid X) = E[H(Y \mid X)] = E[E[I(Y) \mid X]] = E[I(Y)] = H(Y)$$

Can you help me understand where I'm going wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is
$$
H(Y|X)=E[H(Y|X)].
$$
There is no reason for this to be true.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this has been confusing me quite a bit. In regards to the second equality, if you go to this Wikipedia it says $H(X) = E[I(X)]$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory). In regards to the first equality... how would you define $H(Y|X)$... from my book it says $H(Y|X) =  \sum_{j=1}^m H_{X=x_j}(Y)p_X(x_j)$  which looks so much like $E[E[X|Y=y]]$

Comment: @HJ_beginner I have made an edit to reflect the additional info you give in the comment. I suggest you make a new question as you have several notation that is not well-defined given your original post. First, you don't define $I(\cdot)$. Second, you don't define $H(\cdot)$ and you don't define $H_{\ldots}(\cdot)$. I suspect when you can distinguish these 3 $H$-related definitions, your confusion will go away. Good luck.

Comment: If the following is true $$H(X|Y) =  \sum_{j=1}^m H(X|Y=y_j)p_Y(y_j) = \sum_{j=1}^m E[I(X)|Y=y_j]p_Y(y_j) $$
 then that looks so much to me like the law of iterated expectation but it's not.